Vue best practice for calling child's child's functions?
Say you have a vue project where.

The App.vue has a button and a child CanvasView.vue file that sets up the canvas.

The CanvasView.vue file has a child CubeComponent.vue that draws a cube

The CubeComponent.vue has a function "change size" or "change color"


I want to press a button on App.vue that calls the functions in CubeComponent.vue
Is there any standards for situations like this? So far to get this to work Ive been using defineExpose, referencing the child component then defineExpose again.
So in this example I would defineExpose the CubeComponent.vue files functions. Then reference them in CanvasView.vue. defineExpose the referenced CubeComponent.vue file's functions inside CanvasView.vue and reference those functions in App.vue to call them.
Overall this feels wrong.. I feel like theres a better way todo this. Is there?

Just create a .js(or .ts if you are using typescript), write and export the function. Then import it into whatever component that requires that function

It could be done the way you described. Depends on your case. You could do the opposite way and pass data to a grandchild through props. And use global store to skip the hierarchy of components

You can do the following:

provide/inject an event emitter down your hierarchy (from the parent component)
Register an event listener in the emitter (inside your child component).
Emit an event from the parent.

This will keep your code contained and allow you to invoke the method from the parent without exposing anything from the child or needing external state management.
Here is a link to the inject/provider feature of Vue:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject

As the event emitter you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-parent-emit/v/3.0.0 (which I am the author of).

We use this framework for typed events:
https://code-evolve.com/resources/code-extend
https://www.npmjs.com/package/code-extend

Use the Pinia lib and move the "size" and "color" variables into the Pinia store along with the changeSize and changeColor functions. They become "global" and you can use them without "expose", without "provide", without props drilling.
